# F3 - How to connect to FTP on Fat Free Framework?

Tags: php, ftp, fat-free-framework

Does there exist a class in F3 that allow me work with an FTP? I need upload from a web form, and then download from a web page. I need to work with personal documents, and therefore I can't upload it to public folder.

Comment: Have a look at fal: https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/tree/master-v3/FAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Far as I know, F3 has no FTP Class to use.
The code below is a work around.

1. Download this Library: [Nicolab/php-ftp-client](https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client)
2. Copy the three files in `/src/FtpClient/` into a folder named `ftpclient` and then add the folder to your `autoload`.
3. Connect!

   ```
   $ftp = new \FtpClient\FtpClient();
   $ftp->connect($host);
   $ftp->login($login, $password);
   ```
4. Store the connection in your `HIVE`

   ```
   $f3->set('FTP', $ftp);
   //Now you can do : https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client#usage
   //Also extend https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client#extend
   ```